# Get podcasts on my IPhone through iTunes

Tags: windows-7, itunes, iphone

I've gone through the following steps:

- I loaded up iTunes 10 on a Windows7 machine
- I went to the iTunes store and subscribed to a podcast
- Library/podcasts has nothing in it, but there is a 1 in a circle by Podcasts Devices/my Iphone / Sync
- I checked my iPhone, but no podcasts are there

I really don't have a good times with the iTunes software. If someone could provide detailed step by step instructions of how to get podcasts onto my iPhone via iTunes I'd really appreciate it.

I know I can download podcasts direct to my iphone, but I would like to get it working through iTunes if I can.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing has downloaded for the podcast you have suscribed to then there is probably nothing to download.

Have you tried other podcasts?

When you subscribe it should auto-download the lates podcast in that subscription.

As for transferring to the iPhone or an iPod, you have to make sure that Podcasts are turned on in the Sync section:

[image: Enabling podcasts in iTunes]

Comment: Thanks. I'm now trying that. Trouble is it's been syncing for about 30 minutes and is still on Step (1 of 4) backing up! I don't know why iTunes takes so long I only have a few apps and no music or podcats.